# why product title does not print in my home page?

Tags: collections, shopify, product, liquid

I've been searching around on Google to find an accurate tutorial that explains how to display products on the home page but so far nothing is working!  The for loop doesn't work; `{% for product in collections[section.settings.featured_collection].products %} {{ product.title }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Did you check that `section.settings.featured_collection` is an actual collection handle?

Comment: "settings": [{
   "type": "collection",
   "id": "featured_collection",
   "label": "Collection"
  },

Comment: Seems to be correct but to double check you can try to print `{{ section.settings.featured_collection}}`. Also, does the collection contain proucts?

Comment: {{ section.settings.featured_collection }} print this after for loop. it renders "frontpage". i add three product .

Comment: Fabio Filippi, Thank you very much. I can solve it. The collection does not contain the products.